# Explanation of theorem on differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

[image]

This is text from Do Carmo's Differential forms and applications Page-10. Could anyone explain the highlighted step?If f* is applied to each of the term then how do we get the RHS of the highlighted equation as shown in the figure. Thanks.

Comment: There are five equalities, the first one is the definition of $dg$, second the definition of $f^*$, third the chain rule, fourth the definition of $d(g\circ f$ and fifth the definition of $f^* g$.

Comment: Yes and as I mentioned above I am unable to understand how the definition of f* led to the second equality. If we apply f* to each term where each term is a function, say g, multiplied by an elementary form then we get f*(g) f*(dx). Now f*(g) becomes gof and f*(dx) becomes df_i. But how does this relate to what's given above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for $h(y) dy^i$, we have

$$f^*(h(y) dy^i) = (f^* h)(x) df^i = \sum_j h(f(x)) \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j} dx^j = \sum_j h \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j} dx^j.$$

The last step is nothing but suppressing that $f(x)$ from $h(f(x))$ (just notational convenience). Thus

$$\begin{split}
f^*\left( \sum_i \frac{\partial g}{\partial y^i} dy^i \right) &= \sum_i f^*\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y^i} dy^i \right)\\
&= \sum_i \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y^i} \sum_j \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j} dx^j \right) \\
&=\sum_{i,j} \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y^i} \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j} dx^j \right)
\end{split}$$

Comment: Ok so basically you mean to say that frac{\partial g}{\partial y^i} is implicitly composed with f ?

Comment: Yes,  (or the next line would not make sense too when you apply chain rule) @RagingBull